# Save Canvas to Device in Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, canvas, download

I've done a lot of research and testing on this, but am getting compatibility/clarity issues right and left. I was hoping someone had a clear solution for this.

My PhoneGap Build (3.1) application pulls images from S3, adds overlay text to them via html canvas, and then needs to be saved to the user's phone on click action.

Here are some relevant details:

- Preferably they would be saved to a location detectable by the Gallery (android) or the Photos app (iOS).
- I need it to work in Android 2.3 up and iOS 6-7.
- I also have a composited version of the image with overlay text located on AWS. I would be happy with downloading the image to the device either from the composited image's URL or from the canvas directly.

Here are some of my barriers:

- I keep getting "Tainted canvas" security errors when trying to do "canvas.toDataURL()", even though I set a wildcard on S3's CORS permissions for the used bucket.
- The "download" attribute seems to be [unsupported in most mobile browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=download%20attribute).
- I would be happy to use [Phonegap's "FileTransfer.download()" method](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer), but I haven't been able to figure out where I would adequately acquire the right file path on each device for use in Gallery/Photos app

Is there an effective way to get this done cross-platform?

Answer (score 1):

As much as I hate to answer my own question, I found that the PhoneGap plugin called "Canvas2Image" is actually perfect for this: https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin

The description of it is pretty ambiguous in the phonegap plugins directory, but it pretty easily saves the image to the appropriate directory. It takes a success callback, an error callback, and the canvas element as arguments. It also works in both iOS and Android, which was something on which I was unclear due to the phonegap plugins directory description.

```
window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
    function(msg){
        Ext.Msg.alert('Success!', 'The image was saved to the photos gallery on your device.');
    },
    function(err){
        Ext.Msg.alert('Aww, Schucks!', 'There was a problem saving the image to your device.');
    },
    document.querySelector('canvas')
);
```

Note: I wouldn't recommend using `document.querySelector` in Sencha Touch... it's just a clear reference.

Speculative Note: I didn't look into it further, but it appears this may not be a great option if you need to subsequently link to or open the saved image.